# Getting the iframe's URL parameter from within the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, url-parameters

I have an iframe that is loaded on web page and I do not have permissions to access the parent page. I have access to the iframe's code. I would like to access one of the parameters of this iframe. What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried location.search but it does not give me all the parameters.

Any suggestions?
Cheers.

Comment: Have you checked the other properties of the location object? ( href, protocol, hash, host, ... ) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: Yup, I have checked. None of those properties have that parameter.

Comment: When do we know that the iframe has loaded completely? I am currently using $(window).load(function() {}); to identify that.

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you have tried? What are the parameters returned? What is the actual URL? What are the expected parameters?

Comment: window.location gives the location of the parent URL not the iframe URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the answer myself and we can retrieve the iframe's URL using the following code:

```
document.location.href
```

This seems to work fine without any issues.